# Using wheelwidget for android

Tags: android

Iam using `kankans` wheel widget for android, and passing the minutes as below

```
final WheelView mins = (WheelView) view.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
            mins.setViewAdapter(new mywheel(activity, 0, 59,"%02d"));
```

now i want to display my minute values strting with 00 the 05 and continue 06 07..
i want to skip 02,03,04.

```
public class mywheel extends AdapterWheel {

    private int minValue;
    private int maxValue;
     private String format;

      public mywheel(Context context, int minValue, int maxValue, String format) {
            super(context, null);

            this.maxValue = maxValue;
            this.format = format;
        }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < getItemsCount()) {
            int value = 5 * index;
            return format != null ? String.format(format,value) : Integer.toString(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
         return 59 / 5;
    }

}
```

the above code gives me the minute values in multiples of 5, but i just want to skip 2,3,4 .How can i achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: wheel widget for android ,changing minute values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061369/android-wheel-widget-for-android-changing-minute-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class mywheel extends AdapterWheel {

private int minValue;
private int maxValue;
 private String format;

  public mywheel(Context context, int minValue, int maxValue, String format) {
        super(context, null);

        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        this.format = format;
    }

@Override
public CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
    if (index > 0 && index < getItemsCount()) {
        int value = 4 + index;
        return format != null ? String.format(format,value) : Integer.toString(value);
    } else if(index == 0) {
        int value = 0;
        return format != null ? String.format(format,value) : Integer.toString(value);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemsCount() {
     return 56;
}

}
```

Comment: Z   i tried that ,the problem with that is it is starting from 05 not 00 and total minute values are till 15 only..i want it to start with 00 then 05 06...till 59